# Why is my AngularJS code not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please can you help me fix this script:

```
var newsFeed = angular.module('newsFeed', []);

var newsFeedModule = angular.module('newsFeed');

newsFeedModule.controller('newsFeedController', function($scope) {
    $scope.posterWidth = 100;
    $scope.posterHeight = 60;

});
```

html:

```
<div ng-app="newsFeed">
  <div ng-controller="newsFeedController">
    {{ 2+3 }}
    {{ posterWidth }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a simple AngularJS Script that is going to display the variable and expressions as above. But the values are not being calculated. I have tried a few times and you can see the JSFiddle below.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q209o0gm/6/)

Comment: I didn't see the proper use to make another reference of module initialization. You should remove this reference `newsFeedModule` and init controller to `newsFeed` module. It will work and yeah, You should load angular.js on `DOM`.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> use it

Comment: But angularjs is loaded. see 'external resources' on jsfiddle

Comment: @sergey.sergeyd2016 , updated my ans with fiddle .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/omkbLa78/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `JSFiddle` you need to to click on the **JAVASCRIPT** Button and need to select `angular 1.4.8` in `Frameworks & Extensions` dropdown and then select `No wrap in head` option in `Load type` dropdown .... now it will work

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Moumit/q209o0gm/12/)

Answer (score 0):

working example

https://jsfiddle.net/yeLm5j8u/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="newsFeed">
  <div ng-controller="newsFeedController">
    {{ 2+3 }}
    {{ posterWidth }}
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
var newsFeed = angular.module('newsFeed', []);

var newsFeedModule = angular.module('newsFeed');

newsFeedModule.controller('newsFeedController', function($scope) {
    $scope.posterWidth = 100;
    $scope.posterHeight = 60;


});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need the newsFeedModule? You already have the newsFeed. newsFeed.controler('newsFeedController') ...

Answer (score -1):

You **do** need to include AngularJS!

Comment: angularjs is included. see 'external resources' on jsfiddle